# Wrapping sequelize ORM tests in transactions

Tags: javascript, jestjs, sequelize.js

I am looking for an approach to making my test cases that use sequelize ORM transactional. This has been discussed on the sequelize github issues:

- https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4823

Looking for a way to do the following:

```
describe('My test case', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        ... create a transaction
    })

    afterEach(() => {
        ... roll back the transaction
    })

    ..... RUN isolated tests

})
```

I am used to the Django ORM which does this by default in test cases (among of things like automatically managing migrations).

Answer (score 0):

There is an example with Jest and Sequelize in [this article](https://ericyd.hashnode.dev/write-clean-database-tests-with-jest).

With your code example you can do something like this:

```js
import { sequelize } from './connection'

describe('My test case', async () => {
  let transaction;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const cls = new Map();
    Object.defineProperty(cls, 'run', {
      value: fn => {
        fn(this);
        return this;
      },
    });
    transaction = await sequelize.transaction();
    sequelize.constructor._cls = cls;
    sequelize.constructor._cls.set('transaction', transaction);
  })

  afterEach(async () => {
    await transaction.rollback();
  })
  
  // ..... RUN isolated tests

})
```

Of course you can put the `beforeEach` and `afterEach` code in a function and call the function in your test files to avoid duplication.